# Multiple column sort in unix reverse order not working

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, command

I need to arrange the below, in the shown order. First based on 1st column, secondarily based on 3rd column.

```
148672074   ABC 23.77
148672073   ABC 13.77
148672074   ABC 53.77
148672071   ABC 23.77
148672074   ABC 93.77
148672074   ABC 193.77
```

I need it like,

```
148672071   ABC  23.77
148672073   ABC  13.77
148672074   ABC 193.77
148672074   ABC  93.77
148672074   ABC  53.77
148672074   ABC  23.77
```

I used the below command.

```
sort -t "\t" -k1,1n -k3,3rn a.txt >b.txt
```

However, I'm getting the output as

```
148672071   ABC  23.77
148672073   ABC  13.77
148672074   ABC 193.77
148672074   ABC  23.77
148672074   ABC  53.77
148672074   ABC  93.77
```

Somebody Please tell me where I'm going wrong? And kindly give me the right command.

PS: The file I'm using is a TSV format file, exported from an excel sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\t` is recgnized as `t`, not as tab.

Instead of `\t`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to denote tab character.

```
$ sort -t " " -k1,1n -k3,3rn a.txt
148672071   ABC 23.77
148672073   ABC 13.77
148672074   ABC 193.77
148672074   ABC 93.77
148672074   ABC 53.77
148672074   ABC 23.77
```

**UPDATE**

As fedorqui commented, you can also use `$'\t'`:

```
$ sort -t $'\t' -k1,1n -k3,3rn a.txt
148672071   ABC 23.77
148672073   ABC 13.77
148672074   ABC 193.77
148672074   ABC 93.77
148672074   ABC 53.77
148672074   ABC 23.77
```

Comment: You can also use `-t $'\t'`.

Comment: @fedorqui, Thank you for the comment. I'll add that to the answer.